# Importar módulos C++ em python

Tags: python, c++, pycharm

Estou tentando importar em um `script python` um módulo C++:

```
import hector_path_follower
```

O arquivo `c++` define um `namespace` para a classe:

```
namespace pose_follower {
 class HectorPathFollower
 { 
   ...
 }
}
```

No meu script python o `import` é corretamente interpretado, porém ao tentar acessar a um metodo o namespace não é reconhecido.

```
pf = pose_follower.HectorPathFollower()
```

Estou usando a pycharm community edition 2017.3.3

Comment: Assim, eu já até brinquei de fazer um pseudo-módulo em C para Python no Linux. Não lembro exatamente o que eu fiz para dar certo, mas eu acho que uma das coisas importantes para se usar C era o fato de que a ABI do C é estável e padronizada, já a do C++ depende do compilador (e talvez do linkador, não tenho certeza). Para indicar que você quer usar a ABI do C no C++, existe a diretiva `extern "C"`. Isso foi uma coisa que precisei levar em consideração, mas já faz tempo. Não lembro de outros detalhes

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado o caso de "extern" não se aplica meu cado, já que o tenho tudo devidamente definido. O que quero é importá-los e usar o código em python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Módulos em outras linguagens não são usáveis diretamente a partir do Python.

O fato do módulo ser importado é por que o Python pode importar módulos `.so` no Unix ou `.dll` no Windows - mas esses módulos tem que ter estruturas específicas dentro para que elementos de Python sejam visíveis na linguagem.  Para isso é necessário se colocar algumas estruturas de dados e se chamar um registro específico definido na [CPython-API](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) - e de tudo o que eu descrevo abaixo, é o método que dá mais trabalho. Embora, como seja C puro, para quem está acostumado, não vai envolver o aprendizado ou uso de nenhuma outra linguagem intermediária ou tecnologia de configuração.

É ae possível ler direto os `.so` e chamar as funções extern lá dentro, mas para isso é necessário usar o "[ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html)" do Python, e redefenir, do lado do Python, as funções que se quer usar e as structs usadas por elas. C++ tem uma complicação adicional com o esquema dos nomes das funções, mas funcionaria também.

Normalmente o pessoal usa a ferramenta "[swig](http://www.swig.org/)" ou o framework "[boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html)": eles permitem, com apenas um pouco de configuração, a geração automática das ligações em Python de bibliotecas nativas em C++ - se o que você quer usar em C++ está pronto e completo, eu recomendaria o uso de uma dessas duas - mas você vai ter que checar a documentação. Depois do módulo Python gerado por essas ferramentas, é só realmente usar a partir do Python o que você tem em C++.

Uma outra ferramenta ainda é o [Cython](http://cython.org/) - ele é um superconjunto de Python compilado para código nativo - mas também vai depender de definir funções e structs em sua sintaxe própria mais ou menos manualmente antes de serem usadas (e não sei como funciona o Cython para classes em C++ - suponho que tenha um jeito).

E por fim, existe o [cffi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cffi) que também permtie que código Python puro faça as chamadas para código nativo.

Comparando a grosso modo: 
A **CPython API** é a forma "oficial" de  se fazer a ligação para código nativo, usada internamente no próprio projeto do cPython.  Ela exige que cada método, função ou estrutura de dados que seja visível e chamável do Python seja escrita manualmente - dentro desses métodos você faz as chamadas para ler os parâmetros passados e converter os tipos de dados para os usados internamente no seu código C++ (por exemplo, converter um objeto `int` de Python para um int64 de C++ ) - chamar sua função, e conerter os valores de retorno de volta em objetos de Python.  Além disso é preciso listar todas essas funções em Structs específicos para seu registro, de forma que sejam visíveis do Python. É realmente bem trabalhoso. Acredito que dessa forma seja até possível ter um único arquivo .so e ou .dll que funcione diretamente para C e C++ e também para Python. Todas as formas abaixo vão gerar um arquivo secundário para isso.

**ctypes** permite que você escreva todo o código a mais para usar as bibliotecas em C++ em Python puro, como parte do seu programa Python, e não exige nenhuma outra depêndencia - mas há uma certa impedância até entender direito a mecânica do ctypes, e o problema de ter que se definir o equivalente aos protótipos de função e as structs manualmente.Ctypes é muito prático quando você está escrevendo código em Python puro e quer chamar apenas algumas funções de alguma biblioteca que não tenha o adaptador para Python ela permite que sem instalar nenhuma dependência, nem mudar de linguagem, você escreva as chamadas direto em Python.

O **cffi**  - é quase  a mesma coisa que o ctypes. Ele tem ferramentas para ler diretamente os `.h` - mas o cffi não acompanha o Python, e exige uma instalação de uma biblioteca separada a partir do Pypi.

A opção de **Cython**, na minha opinião, faz mais sentido quando alguém que não é o autor da biblioteca original em C ou C++ quer deixar  pronto o módulo compilado em Python para uso de terceiros - como você etá com tudo na mão aí, acho que não é o caso. Como escrito acima, depende de se escrever um código adaptador específico.

**Swig** e **Boost** funcionam melhor com intervenção no pacote de C++ , ou pelo menos dependem de ter os `.h` e `.hpp` disponíveis - mas uma vez configurados corretamente, o modulo intermediário para Python é gerado e pode ser instalado diretamente com os binários que o C++ gera; para terceiros que vão programar em Python e fazer uso do seu código de C++, essas duas podem ser a melhor opção. Nunca usei o suficiente nenhuma delas pra saber qual é melhor. Acho que o Swig é mais simples. Inclusive ele tem entende os namespaces - veja a seção 36.3.12 em http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_nn2

Acho que vale a pena você dar uma olhada no Swig primeiro. Se ele for complicado para C++, veja o Boost, que é nativo para C++ - se ainda tiver dificuldades, aí avalie as outras.